# Writing linear combination of exponentials as cosine

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Show that $$y = A_1e^{ix} + A_2e^{-ix}$$
can be written as $$y = A\cos(x - \delta)$$ where A and $\delta$ are real.

So far I have done the following:
$$y = (A+B)\cos(x) + (A-B) i\sin(x)$$

Am I on the right track? I can't seem to figure out where to go next.

Comment: Should the coefficients be conjugate? Otherwise $y$ might not be real.

Comment: The question didn't specify that the coefficients are conjugate...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Since 
$$ A_1e^{ix} + A_2e^{-ix}= A\cos(x - \delta)$$
must hold for any $x$, write it for $x=0$  and $x=\frac \pi 2$. This gives
$$A_1+A_2=A \cos (\delta )$$
$$i(A_1-A_2)=A \sin (\delta )$$
Start squaring both equations and add them; this could give $A$. Make the ratio to get $\tan(\delta )$.